# ExchangeService instance or GetUserAvailabilityResults with given TimeZone for Microsoft EWS

Tags: java, timezone, exchangewebservices

I am having a problem with using timezones with Exchange2010_SP2. My goal is to retrieve all data (clientEvents to be precisely) with UTC date format. As I read in the documentation by default it returns data in system's current time zone if no configuration for time zones is provided. I would like to avoid that. I want to use only UTC for getting my data. I read that there is possibility to use this construction to do so:

```
ExchangeService serviceEST = new ExchangeService(TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time"));
```

but above code simply does compile, there is no class TimeZoneInfo - code is from C# documentation, but I was not able to find anything else.
In old version of API ther was constructor

```
ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion requestedServerVersion, TimeZone timeZone)
```

but is is gone now, why? Currently in constructors method headers in ExchangeService class, I see always term "...to the system's current time zone." Is there a way to configure new instance of ExchangeService with given TimeZone?
I thought maybe that method getUserAvailability has some possibility to force service to retrieve data in particular/given time zone. Although this has additional parameter AvailabilityOptions, it does not provide option for TimeZone. Data I retrieve actually have TimeZone object, but it seems like it does not work correctly. The name of a time zone is "Custom time zone". Info is stored in AttendeeAvaialability->workingHours->timeZone.
I am also not able to get the current/local/default time zone that EWS service is using. I can get the list of all available time zones, but I can not see a way to get the current/local one that is used.
So am in a bit of a pickle here. What I was able to do is this:

```
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));    
final ExchangeService instance = new ExchangeService();
```

This will change the hole app to use UTC time zone. It is not the cleanest way to do it, I would really like to avoid this kind of hardcoding, but it seems like it is the only way, or am I wrong ?

Any help would be much appreciated,

cheers,
Pawel

Comment: The EWS API's for both Java and .NET have been retired as of July 2018.  See [the announcement here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/blogs/upcoming-changes-to-exchange-web-services-ews-api-for-office-365/).  The general recommendation is to use the [Microsoft Graph SDK](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-java) instead.

Comment: Thank you @MattJohnson-Pint for pointing that out. I am aware that Graph is the way to go especially in 2020, but in my case this can be done just like that. A lot depends on the klient and time, as you probably know - this is just the way business works. Anyway, thanks for sharing that information.